# Laravel 5.6 - Auth don't work in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I make many projects with Laravel 5.6 with the same login setup (Use Auth facade), but with one shared hosting the users can't log in. When you enter the correctly mail and password, only reload de login page **WITHOUT ANY ERRORS**, when in my controller all the views return errors or a message.

This is the code of my login (Works in all servers except in this):

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|min:3|max:88',
        'password' => 'required|min:3|max:88',
    );

    $messages = [
        'required' => 'El :attribute es requerido',
        'email' => 'Tiene que ingresar un mail válido',
        'min' => 'Longitud del campo :attribute no válido',
        'max' => 'Longitud del campo :attribute no válido',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->intended('admin')->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended('admin')->withErrors(['loginFail' => 'Usuario/Contraseña incorrectos']);
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter a wrong email or password in any server, this return me to the login view with the errors, but in these the errors don't appear and I can't login with the correct email and password.

I call to the hosting and say me that is nothing wrong, how can i solve it?

Comment: My advice, frankly, is to avoid shared hosting for Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz it's impossible that option because my client want stay in that hosting... but it's very strange and I can't solve this problem

Comment: Sometimes our job is to educate the client. VPS hosting can be had for free on most of the major clouds, or as low as $5/month at a place like DigitalOcean.

Comment: Try check the permissions of storage directory. One other thing, is php error reporting on the shared hosting configuration enabled?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra hi, i put 777 to all storage directory and yes, errors are enabled

Comment: are sessions working correctly?

Comment: @lagbox how can i test the sessions? Because i think that this is the problem

Comment: Try with `return back()->withInput();` in first part of if block instead.